# Why am I getting error ORA-01427: Single-row Subquery Returns More Than One Row

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

Why am I getting error message?

> ORA-01427: Single-row Subquery Returns More Than One Row with this query

```
UPDATE JOB_TASK JT1
   SET JT1.job_task_status_id =
          (SELECT JTS1.JOB_TASK_STATUS_ID
             FROM MAXIMO_WO MW1
                  INNER JOIN job_task_status jts1
                     ON MW1.STATUS = jts1.description
                     INNER JOIN JOB_TASK JT1
                     ON jt1.job_task_id = mw1.wonum)
WHERE   JT1.JOB_TASK_STATUS_ID IN
          (SELECT JTS.JOB_TASK_STATUS_ID
             FROM JOB_TASK_STATUS JTS,
                  JOB_TASK JT,
                  MAXIMO_WO MW,
                  WORK_ORDER_CONTROL WOC
            WHERE     JT.JOB_TASK_ID = MW.WONUM
                  AND JT.JOB_TASK_STATUS_ID = JTS.JOB_TASK_STATUS_ID
                  AND JT.WORK_ORDER_ID = WOC.WORK_ORDER_ID
                  and jt.job_task_id = mw.wonum
                  AND MW.STATUS IN
                         ('APPR',
                          'SCHED',
                          'INPRG',
                          'FNACCEPT',
                          'WMATL',
                          'WKCOMP',
                          'COMP')
                  AND WOC.COMPANY_ID = '21'
                  AND MW.SITEID <> 'NUCDEV'
                  AND DECODE (
                         INSTR (JTS.DESCRIPTION, '-', 1),
                         0, JTS.DESCRIPTION,
                         SUBSTR (JTS.DESCRIPTION,
                                 1,
                                 (INSTR (JTS.DESCRIPTION, '-', 1) - 1))) <>
                         MW.STATUS
                  AND JT.LEVEL_NUMBER = '3'
                  AND MW.STATUSDATE < SYSDATE - 1
                  AND MW.WONUM <> 'UNDEFINED')
```

Comment: Because your subquery is returning more than one row.

Comment: If you run the `SELECT` from your `SET`, how many rows do you return?

Comment: @swasheck Can you show some evidence for this?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO the error

Comment: This is one of the few errors in Oracle that is _always_ what it means @FreshPrinceOfSO. There's no ambiguity. The sub-query is returning more than one row.

Comment: @Ben I may have been pulling swashecks leg

Comment: @Ben - to be fair there are two subqueries; only one is causing the error, so for a newbie-level question, there is at least SOME ambiguity... for anyone reading this in the future, that's an important point. Also that the subselect in the SET portion is unnecessary.  Still, definitely a dupe, I'm all for closing it.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you really want the subselect in the SET portion of the statement.  Try something like this:

```
 UPDATE JT1
    SET JT1.job_task_status_id = JTS1.JOB_TASK_STATUS_ID
 FROM MAXIMO_WO MW1
      INNER JOIN job_task_status jts1
            ON MW1.STATUS = jts1.description
      INNER JOIN JOB_TASK JT1
            ON jt1.job_task_id = mw1.wonum
 WHERE   JT1.JOB_TASK_STATUS_ID IN
      (SELECT JTS.JOB_TASK_STATUS_ID
         FROM JOB_TASK_STATUS JTS,
              JOB_TASK JT,
              MAXIMO_WO MW,
              WORK_ORDER_CONTROL WOC
        WHERE     JT.JOB_TASK_ID = MW.WONUM
              AND JT.JOB_TASK_STATUS_ID = JTS.JOB_TASK_STATUS_ID
              AND JT.WORK_ORDER_ID = WOC.WORK_ORDER_ID
              and jt.job_task_id = mw.wonum
              AND MW.STATUS IN
                     ('APPR',
                      'SCHED',
                      'INPRG',
                      'FNACCEPT',
                      'WMATL',
                      'WKCOMP',
                      'COMP')
              AND WOC.COMPANY_ID = '21'
              AND MW.SITEID <> 'NUCDEV'
              AND DECODE (
                     INSTR (JTS.DESCRIPTION, '-', 1),
                     0, JTS.DESCRIPTION,
                     SUBSTR (JTS.DESCRIPTION,
                             1,
                             (INSTR (JTS.DESCRIPTION, '-', 1) - 1))) <>
                     MW.STATUS
              AND JT.LEVEL_NUMBER = '3'
              AND MW.STATUSDATE < SYSDATE - 1
              AND MW.WONUM <> 'UNDEFINED')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as the error indicates, the subquery in your SET statement is returning multiple values:

```
SELECT JTS1.JOB_TASK_STATUS_ID
             FROM MAXIMO_WO MW1
                  INNER JOIN job_task_status jts1
                     ON MW1.STATUS = jts1.description
                     INNER JOIN JOB_TASK JT1
                     ON jt1.job_task_id = mw1.wonum
```

Because this query is not connected in anyway to your outer UPDATE statement. I know, I know, you used the same alias for the JOB_TASK table! But that's just a coincidence as far as Oracle's concerned because you re-joined the JOB_TASK table to the query.  This query will basically return *every* job_task, its work order data, and its task status.

What you need is just to reference your outside alias:

```
UPDATE JOB_TASK JT1
   SET JT1.job_task_status_id =
          (SELECT JTS1.JOB_TASK_STATUS_ID
             FROM MAXIMO_WO MW1
                  INNER JOIN job_task_status jts1
                     ON MW1.STATUS = jts1.description
                     and MW1.MoNum = jt1.job_task_id )
...
```

This will properly use your outside JOB_TASK's job_task_id to get its task_status_id.